# looping through input and seeing occurence in it

Tags: python, loops, count

Im trying to count how many times the user input a a url of http:// at the beginning of their respond or preceded by a space or end of the tweet
The problem is that no matter what i input in tweet it always stays at 0 and even if its spamming http:// it still stays at 0

```
def count_url(tweet):
count = 0
for word in tweet:
    if word.startswith('http://') or word.endswith('http://'):
        count = count + 1
return count
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: it always stays at 0 no matter what i type in even if its spamming http://

Comment: Edit your question. Please provide sample inputs you are providing, and explain in your question exactly what is not working. You are now asking the reader to guess what the problem is. Which is not helpful.

Comment: I get the feeling `tweet` is a single string.

Comment: yeah its just count_url("http:// I have a link http:// called http://")

Answer (score 0):

You are inputting tweets in your function, which are strings. So, if you have a tweet like:

```
"I love potatoes, buy some here http://potatoesarethebest.com"
```

And iterate over that, you are iterating over the *characters* and not the words. What you need to do is *split* the string in to a *list*, by calling the `split` method on it, which will by default split on spaces:

```
>>> s = "I love potatoes, buy some here http://potatoesarethebest.com"
>>> s.split()
['I', 'love', 'potatoes,', 'buy', 'some', 'here', 'http://potatoesarethebest.com']
```

Which means in your function, all you need to do when iterating over your `tweet`, is to simply call `split()`. Also, you can simply use `count += 1` instead of `count = count + 1`

With this method, it also does not make sense to have `word.endswith('http://')`. `endswith` looks for parts of the string that end in the match. So you are looking for something like "thisishttp://". Which does not make much sense.

```
def count_url(tweet):
    count = 0
    for word in tweet.split():
        if word.startswith('http://'):
            count += 1
    return count
```

Demo:

```
>>> res = count_url("I love potatoes, buy some here http://potatoesarethebest.com")
>>> print(res)
1
```

The limitation with this solution is that it will not work if you have a string like:

```
"this is awesome check here:http://www.stuff.com"
```

There are other limitations you have to be aware of. So, you also need to be aware of what exact criteria you are looking to use to perform your matching.